# I am trying to display response of json in UITableViewCell but not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

[image]

Hi I am trying to display response like in this image but not display and some error are occurs so please help me

```
-(void)getCategories
{
    Service *srv=[[Service alloc]init];

    NSString *str=@"http://streamtvbox.com/site/api/matrix/";//?country_code=91&phone=9173140993&fingerprint=2222222222";
    NSString *method=@"channels";
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObj);
        arrayCategories = [responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"];
     }];
 }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrayCategories.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChannelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     }

     cell.textLabel.text = [[arrayCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"categories"];

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: When and where do you call method "getCategories"?
I'm not sure, but look like you should reload tableView in the end of "getCategories" method.

Comment: `responseObj` is an array or dictionary?

Comment: @Birendra Please give more details, regarding the response structure, but here reload tableview is missing

Comment: In responseObj where is the "categories" key?

Answer (score 0):

After you receive the response please reload,

```
 [srv postToURL:str withMethod:method andParams:dict completion:^(BOOL success, NSDictionary *responseObj)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObj);
        arrayCategories = [responseObj valueForKey:@"categories"];
    [youTableView reloadDate];
     }];
```

Comment: [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Apparently your arrayCategories object is not an array, but a dictionary - but you try to access it as array in your cellATRowForIndexPath function ...

Comment: @Birendra please give me your array structure :)